# Can't read data from Azure Database /w Android, Inserting data with Delay, Any Suggestions?

Tags: android, database, azure, delay

I am trying to develope an amateur Android Application with Azure Table Storage, i handled to create a database and connect to it. When i want to insert a data,

```
JsonObject obje = new JsonObject();
obje.addProperty("id","a");
    obje.addProperty("NUMERO", 3);
    mClient.getTable("deneme").insert(obje);
```

this code works but with a 10 seconds delay and when i want to read this data from table with this code

```
 try {
                     this.sr = mClient.getTable("deneme").where().field("id").eq("a").execute().get().toString();
 }
 catch (Exception z) {
                          AlertDialog alertDialog3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this).create();
                          alertDialog3.setTitle("Alert");
                          alertDialog3.setMessage("Err" + count);
                          alertDialog3.show();
 }
```

it gives blackscreen and stays as that, not even throws exception, doesn't stop working..

Now, am i using query code wrong because i couldn't find a simple query example about that.

-Using General Mobile Android One with Android 6... Api 23.

-All permissions is granted at AndroidManifest and also on Runtime.

Also is there any other way to create an online database for android maybe faster and easier? Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you clarify which Database offering you are using? DocumentDB, Azure SQL DB, Table Storage, other? It will make it more likely someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you, i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

This first thing to note about Table Storage isn't that isn't designed for relational-type data. The quickest lookups for data in Table Storage are based on using the built-in Partition and Row key columns - anything else is unlikely to be performant. You may want to consider [DocumentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/) or [Azure Mobile Apps Easy Tables](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-mobile-apps-november-2015-update/) instead.